# Как перенаправить трафик с помощью iptables?

Tags: linux, proxy, redirect, iptables, firewall

Допустим есть сайт exampleee.com. Когда пользователь делает запрос то он проходит через firewall-прокси где учитывая его ip адрес он перенаправляется либо на "хороший" сервер либо на "плохой". Но если пользователь сделал запрос на "хороший" сервер, провел какие то действия, а после его ip попал в списки плохих адресов то все дальнейшие запросы все равно будут поступать на "хороший" сервер, не смотря на то что ему запрещено по условию iptables.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m set -j DNAT --to-destination $GOOD_SERVER --match-set goodlist src
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m set -j DNAT --to-destination $BAD_SERVER --match-set badlist src
```

Если сначала ip адрес в goodlist а в процессе его запросов он был удален из goodlist и добавлен в blacklist то все его запросы все равно попадут на GOOD_SERVER

Как сделать так чтобы условия перепроверялись каждый раз? Или здесь что то другое?

Comment: А почему в первом правиле tcp, а во втором — udp?

Comment: Случайно, копировал шаблон и потом правил под свой